# Easiest way to self-join one table to create "AND-filter"?

Tags: mysql, sql, filter, self-join

I have the following (very simple) table:

```
| A | Z |
|---|---|
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 |
```

Now I want to filter the values in this table by Z and find all As that match my filter.
The Z-Filter should behave like an AND-filter. Here are some examples with matching queries:

```
-- filter z= 1
-- expect a = 1,2
select a from data where z = 1;

-- filter z= 5
-- expect a = 2
select a from data where z = 5;

-- filter z= -
-- expect a = 1,2
select a from data;
```

**Now here comes the problem:  I want to filter by z=1 AND z=5**

```
-- filter z: 1,5
-- expect a = 2
```

Using "in" will *not* give the result I want. It's like saying z=1 OR z=5.

```
select a from data where z in (1,5);
```

I want an AND-join to the z-filter. I know it can be done like this:

```
select d1.a from data d1
  left join data d2 on (d1.a = d2.a)
  where d1.z = 1
  and d2.z = 5;
```

The thing is that the z-filter-list can grow dynamically and for every z-value I have to add another join. So my question is: **Is there an easier way to do this?**

SQLFiddle with the above examples: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03d07/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY/HAVING`:

```
SELECT  a
FROM    data 
WHERE   z IN (1,5)
GROUP BY a
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT z) = 2; -- NUMBER OF ITEMS IN THE IN CLAUSE
```

So although you are saying `z` can be 1 or 5, your `HAVING` limits this to only values of `a` that have both.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03d07/10)**

Comment: Oh you already had the answer, sorry did not see it , deleting mine its a duplicate one.

Comment: Awesome! I knew there had to be another way. Thank you very much. :D

Comment: But what's the need of distinct.

Comment: @siddhesh There is no mention in the question that the tuple `(a, z)` is constrained to be unique, therefore you could have two rows with values  `(1, 1), (1, 1)`, this satisfies both `z in (1, 5)` and `COUNT(z) = 2`, however, there is not a value for z = 5, therefore it should not be returned. With a slight modification of the demo on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6f2e0c/1) without distinct the query incorrectly returns 3 in the second query.

Comment: Thank you @GarethD sir. Today  I am totally going cracked for this issue in office whole day and  last I think self join is solution so i think about the disadvantages of join and research again about this topic find this answer and very happy. will you please tell me Where I can find like this sql queries to study more  about advanced sql tricks .

Comment: @GarethD Sir I still have one doubt how to do it for multiple with groups i.e. if we use this for any shopping cart project then there is the attributes group say color and size so when i say i want to filter by color green and blue with size s it means i want combination of green-s and blue-s but is it possible with this. please reply asap

Comment: If you have a different scenario then please ask a new question. The comments section is for clarification of this answer and this question, not new ones. Thanks